# Docker - run image from docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have set up a docker-compose.yml file that runs a web service along with postgres.

It works nicely when I run it with *docker-compose up*.

***docker-compose.yml:***

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

***Dockerfile:***

```
FROM python:3
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /code/

CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver"]
```

Is there any way to construct an image out of the services?

I tried it with docker-compose build, but running the created image simply freezes the terminal.

Thanks!

Comment: try `docker-compose up --build` than `docker images` to check your images

Answer (score 1):

`docker-compose` is a **container orchestration tool**, albeit a simple one , and not a **bundler** of multiple images and preferences into one. In fact, **such a thing does not even exists**.

What happens when you run `docker-compose up` is that it effectively runs `docker-compose build` for those images that need to be built, `web` in your example, and then effectively replaces the `build: .` with `image: web` and executes the configuration as defined by the compose file.

So if you were to run `docker-compose build` manually and wanted to run the same configuration you have in the compose file manually, you would need to something along the lines of (in order)

- run `docker-compose build` or `docker build -t web .` to build the `web` image
- run `docker run --name db postgres`
- run `docker run --name web -v .:/code -p 8000:8000 web python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`